# Count how many integers are covered by union of intervals in java

Tags: java, integer, union, hashset

I was taking the online challenges from Hackerrank, and there is a question about finding how many integers are covered by union of intervals.  Basically, for the sample testcase 1 (see below pic), among two lines, from first line (1-3 ), we can have the integer 1,2,3, and from the second line, we can obtain 9,10,11,12. So, the final output should be 1,2,3,9,10,11,12, so it will print out 7 as the final output.  However, please see below my implementation for more information.  When I submit my code, I passed all test cases with no errors except for 5 testcases due to time-out issue. So, I am just wondering if someone can please give me some feedback about what wrong with my code. And can anybody fix my code to fix my time-out issue?

Thanks in advance! [image].

[image]

```
Hashset <Integer>mytree = new HashSet<Integer>();
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int N = sc.nextInt();
for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
    int Li = sc.nextInt;
    int Ri = sc.nextInt;
    int current =Li;
    while(current<Ri){
        mytree.add(current);
        current++;
    }
 }

 System.out.println(mytree.size());
```

Comment: *You* chose to accept the HackerRank challenge, so it is *you* that needs to find a solution, not us. **Your code doesn't even compile!!**

Comment: @Andreas , I think you are missing the point!  Do you know what Stackoverflow is about?  This is the platform that people who are learning programming here to ask our problems/errors instead of posting all correct solutions. Plus, my code wont' compile cuz there is no main function in it. All you need is copy my code and paste it under the public void main line, and it will compile.  Additionally, if you cannot help troubleshoot my problem, do not even write and comment unless u can give good feedback !

Comment: 1) Yes, I know what StackOverflow is about. If you check my rep, you should realize I probably know *at least* as well as you do. --- 2) *"can anybody fix my code"* is not a request for help figuring the problem out, it's a request for writing the code for you, aka for solving the challenge for you. --- 3) Your code doesn't compile because `nextInt` is a *method*, not a field. You're missing the `()`. --- 4) I wrote the comment to inform you why I down-voted your question, as a courtesy, aka *"good feedback"*.

Answer (score 2):

As L and R are ranging from 0 to 1,000,000,000.
So, 1,000,000,000*100,000 will certainly get TLE.
You have to avoid inner loop.
My idea is,

- sort all intervals
- loop through intervals and L(i) < R(i-1) then set L(i) = R(i-1)+1
- unionSize = 0
- loop through intervals and unionSize = unionSize + (Ri-Li+1)
- return unionSize

Then big O of N,max loop count 3*100,000

Hopefully it will work
If I manage time laterI will code it for you

Comment: Thanks for your pseudocode.  I appreciated that.  I believe that I received the time-out issue when the input is too large.

Comment: *"sort all intervals"* means *O(n* log *n)*. --- If input intervals are `1-10, 3-6`, step 2 would result in `1-10, 11-6`, and step 4 calculates `(10-1+1) + (6-11+1) = 10 + -4 = 6`, which is not the right answer. --- Lower range is 1, not 0. --- Don't *"I will code it for you"*. It's a challenge for OP to solve. If you want to solve it for yourself, that's fine, but leave the challenge for others to solve by themselves. --- Otherwise, good answer. +1

Comment: Hi Andreas, thanks for your comment, I have not thought about this type 1-10, 3-6 cases

Answer (score 0):

I think the simple and easy solution is just put all interval numbers into the HashSet and it will take duplicate and then you just get the size of HashSet which is the number of union number interval